# Como eliminar caracteres en una cadena string en C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tengo un problema al cortar esta cadena `string`. Yo la obtengo por scanner, pero el scanner me tira prefijos y sufijos y los deseo eliminar. El código me funciona con una cadena como esta `~200|12345678~` y me retorna `12345678`. Pero en ocasiones el código escaneado es más pequeño y se cae el programa.

La variable `ordr` viene de un textbox y la proceso en una clase.

```
public string limpio()
{

    if (ordr == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Presione OK para cotinuar " + "\n" + "sin digiar Manufacturing Order", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }

    else
    {

        int cadena = ordr;
        if (cadena < 14)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe de contener mas digitos", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
        if (cadena >= 14)
        {
            ordr = Convert.ToString(ordr.Substring(5,8));
        }
    }
    return ordr;
}
```

Lo que necesito es que en el momento de escanear se me eliminen los prefijos y sufijos que trae por defecto el escaner. Un ejemplo de un numero escaneado es `~200|12345678~`. Lo que necesito eliminar es el `~200|` del principio y el `~` del final sin importar la cantidad que halla entre esos caracteres **(~200|,~)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con una sola sentencia usando [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string limpio = Regex.Replace(ordr, @"^~200\|(.*)~$", "$1");
```

Explicación:

- `^~200\|` busca `~200|` al principio de la cadena.
- `~$` busca `~` al final de la cadena.
- `(.*)` corresponde a cualquier carácter entre el prefijo y el sufijo.
- `$1` corresponde a la parte `(.*)` del parámetro *pattern*. O sea que solo retiene los caracteres en medio del prefijo y el sufijo.

[Demostración](http://rextester.com/EGO70256).

Comment: Buenisimo, gracias..

Answer (score 1):

Según veo, en tu pregunta usas `Substring(int, int)` puedes darle un mejor uso si el `~200|` del principio siempre estará ahí, de la siguiente manera:

```
ordr = ordr.Substring(5, ordr.Length - 2);
// El - 2 elimina el ~ del final.
```

Con la propiedad length de la variable `ordr` si es que es un `string`, puedes tomar sólo lo que está luego del 200.

Otra cosa, la asignación del `string ordr` al `int cadena`, si no me equivoco, no es válido sin una conversión.

Si la variable `cadena` busca obtener la longitud de `ordr`, la asignación correcta sería:

```
int cadena = ordr.Length;
```

El último detalle sería, no necesitas convertir a `string` el resultado de `Substring`, de por sí este ya retorna un `string`.

Dicho esto, he modificado tu códugo un poco, *(sólo por diversión y tiempo sin usar C#)*:

```
public string limpio() { 
    if (ordr != "") { 
        int cadena = ordr.Length; 
        if (cadena < 14) { 
            MessageBox.Show("Debe de contener mas digitos", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop); 
        } 
        if (cadena >= 14) { 
            ordr = ordr.Substring(5, ordr.Length - 2); 
        }
    } 
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Presione OK para cotinuar " + "\n" + "sin digiar Manufacturing Order", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    return ordr; 
}
```

La razón por la que cambié el orden de las condiciones era porque pensaba recomendarlo, pero el código generado no es muy diferente, así que, ahí está.

Espero haberte ayudado! :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya es lo que deseas hacer, lo que ocupas es usar el método `Split()`

```
String[] ArrayCadenas = cadena.Split("charADividir")
```

Esto te devolverá un array con N números de String, donde N es la cantidad de caracteres que coinciden en la cadena original + 1;

Ejemplo:

```
String cadena = "~200|12345678~";
String arrCadenas = cadena.Split("|");
foreach(string s in arrCadenas)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s + "\n");
}
```

**Salida:**

> ~200
>
> 12345678~

Ahora creo que lo que deseas es hacer esto:

public string limpiar()
{
        if (ordr == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Presione OK para cotinuar " + "\n" + "sin digiar Manufacturing Order", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }

```
    else
    {

        int cadena = ordr;
        if (cadena < 14)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe de contener mas digitos", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
        if (cadena >= 14)
        {
            string[] arr = ordr.Split(|);

            ordr = Convert.ToString(arr[1].Replace("~", ""));
        }
    }
    return ordr;
```

}

Nota: Sí no hay ninguna coincidencia, entonces habrá solo una cadena que será la original

Comment: Y una pregunta, cómo haces para eliminar contrabarras? ( '\' )